# Can I gift games after I've already bought them?

Tags: xbox-one

I wanted to buy a game to gift to my friend, but unfortunately, when I bought it, I forgot to do it as a gift. Now I am the owner of this copy of the game.

Can I give the ownership of my purchased copy of the game to my friend without having to buy it again as a gift?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to gift on the actual console. But you can order those game claim codes from Amazon or Ebay and send it to their email.

When they get the claim code they have to do this:

1. Go to the Microsoft store and scroll down to claim code.
2. Enter the code given and your all set!

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me some time ago, and the direct answer is no. BUT there's a workaround.

After the purchase I found into the Microsoft Store "small letters" that the purchase can be refunded if this is purchased as an error. So what I did is to contact the xbox customer's support and I explained them that my little nephew did the purchase and I had no password for that.

The customer's support pushed me to almost swear that I will put attention on that and put a password on my console, etc... But they did the refund to my credit card and removed the game from my library. After that I did the right gift purchase.

Answer (score -1):

I assume this question is old but ill answer anyways. you go to the game, add-on, or movie of your move 2 over 2 the right, and there will be a button labeled "Buy as gift" you then enter a Gamertag or find a friend of who you want to gift to, and then you may enter a custom message if you desire but this isn't required but can be fun if you're creative with it. you must then confirm the purchase and they will receive the gift within a few minutes.

So to answer you question quickly, yes.